# Why do I get "NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `params' for main:Object with rake db:seed"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, authlogic

I have a model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_update :randomize_file_name

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :birth_date, :gender,:address,:city,:country,:landline,:mobile, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:login,:terms_and_policy,:remember_token,:avatar, :readonly,:look
  attr_accessor :terms_and_policy, :remember_me, :readonly, :password_confirmation
```

And `seeds.rb`:

```
login = Faker::Name.first_name
first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
email = Faker::Internet.email

user = User.create!(login: login, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email, address: "indore", city: "indore", country: "india", mobile:"1234567890", gender: "Male", password: "111111",password_confirmation: "111111")
puts "#{user} is created #{login}"
```

When I run `rake db:create`, I'm getting the error:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `params' for main:Object
```

I do not use `password_confirmation` when I create `user`, because it raises a validation error.

When I trace it:

```
rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
undefined method `params' for main:Object
```

I used the `authlogic` gem when I saw that `params` was defined:

```
module Authlogic
module ControllerAdapters # :nodoc:
# Allows you to use Authlogic in any framework you want, not just rails. See the RailsAdapter or MerbAdapter
# for an example of how to adapt Authlogic to work with your framework.
class AbstractAdapter
  attr_accessor :controller

  def initialize(controller)
    self.controller = controller
  end

  def authenticate_with_http_basic(&block)
    @auth = Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(controller.request.env)
    if @auth.provided? and @auth.basic?
      block.call(*@auth.credentials)
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def cookies
    controller.cookies
  end

  def cookie_domain
    raise NotImplementedError.new("The cookie_domain method has not been implemented by the controller adapter")
  end

  def params
    controller.params
  end

  def request
    controller.request
  end

  def request_content_type
    request.content_type
  end

  def session
    controller.session
  end

  def responds_to_single_access_allowed?
    controller.respond_to?(:single_access_allowed?, true)
  end

  def single_access_allowed?
    controller.send(:single_access_allowed?)
  end

  def responds_to_last_request_update_allowed?
    controller.respond_to?(:last_request_update_allowed?, true)
  end

  def last_request_update_allowed?
    controller.send(:last_request_update_allowed?)
  end

  private
    def method_missing(id, *args, &block)
      controller.send(id, *args, &block)
    end
end
```

end

Comment: `rake db:create` is supposed to create your database and the tables following your `schema.rb`, not to run the seed (try `rake db:seed`)

Comment: Can you run `rake db:create --trace` and locate the line that actually raises the exception? And post it here? Btw, the `seeds.rb` is not used when you only run the `db:create` task.

Comment: But I want to insert admin data into table using seed. So how I can do that

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
undefined method `params' for main:Object
```

may indicate that something is calling `params` outside of a class or module definition. `main:Object` is usually `self` when you have code being executed outside of a class or module definition, e.g.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p392 :001 > self.class
 => Object 
1.9.3p392 :002 > self.inspect
 => "main"
```

Since the problem is happening in a Rake task, try adding the following at the top of your Rakefile:

```
require 'tracer'
Tracer.on
```

Then run:

```
rake db:seed
```

and you will probably see where that is happening.

Comment: Tracer.on ::NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `on' for Tracer:Class

Comment: Somethings wrong then, because that method has been part of Ruby's stdlib for a long time, and what I said to do works for me. Here is the apidoc in [1.8.6](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html#method-c-on), [1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html#method-c-on), [2.0.0](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html#method-c-on). What does `Tracer.method(Tracer.instance_methods[0]).source_location` return?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I noticed something or is it just me, but you have:

```
login = Faker::Name.first_name
first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
email = Faker::Internet.email
```

but then when you try to create it your doing:

```
user = User.create!( login: login, 
                 first_name: first_name, 
                 last_name: last_name, 
                 email: email, 
                 address: "indore", 
                 city: "indore", 
                 country: "india", 
                 mobile:"1234567890", 
                 gender: "Male", 
                 password: "111111",
                 password_confirmation: "111111")
```

Inside the `create` block should you not be doing `login: first_name` instead of being `login: login`. And anyways here is another example for you maybe this will help you out:

```
 20.times do |n|

      email = Faker::Internet.email
      until User.find_by_email( email ) === nil
        email = Faker::Internet.email
      end

      login = Faker::Name.first_name
      first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
      last_name = Faker::Name.last_name

      d = User.create!(:login => name,
                   :full_name => fullname,
                   :email => email,
                   :password => password,
                   :password_confirmation => password,
                    )        
end
```

What this does is creates 20 users with the relevant information supplied inside the `do` loop.